# Getting the link that executed the application when launching from web c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have a Winform application that is opened from a web report

I want to save all the URLs that redirect to open my app.

I've tried:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
Application.ExecutablePath;
```

they all give something like:

> c:\Users...\appdata\local\blah..blah\MyApp.exe

and I'm looking for something like

> http://Myserver/Myapp/Application/Myapp.application?var=x

Comment: How is the windows form opened? Please show the code. Your question needs to provide more info if you want an answer.

Comment: CodingYoshi. i just did.
i executed my application from something like the second quote and that is what I'm trying to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below line of code to get the launch URI

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri
```

For limitations and usage look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172242.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! that worked! and i commented another thing i found that works also, do you know the differences between the two?

Comment: AFAIK, the ApplicationDeployment class is to manage and work with 'ClickOnce' deployed applications. The one that you have mentioned is general one not specific to 'ClickOnce' apps.

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a way to do this with this property:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0];
```

and as Thangadurai answered, also worked:

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri
```